# Flying from San Francisco to Palm Springs via Phoenix. Will I have to re-claim and re-check bags at Phoenix?

Tags: luggage, airports

I'll by flying from San Francisco to Phoenix and then Pheonix to Palm Springs. The layover at Phoenix is just 1 hour.

Was booked through British Airways and all flights have the same booking reference.

Looks like American Airlines are operating these flights.

Will I have to reclaim and check my bags again at Pheonix? Do I need to do anything particular at San Francisco airport to ensure my bags end up in Palm Springs easily?

Thanks in advance for your reply!

Comment: Just make sure that when you check-in your bags in SFO they are tagged to the final destination. The check-in agent should ask you where you are flying to, just say "Palm Springs via Phoenix" and it should all happen automatically: you should get boarding passes for both flights, and the luggage tags should have both cities listed.

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to find what this question is a duplicate of but I can't find any. Perhaps others found this self evident and haven't asked. Anyways, since you are flying on a single ticket within a single country your luggage goes through to the end. International is different but that definitely has duplicates.

Comment: Since it sounds like the op may not be well travelled on the US, I can see where the question came from: when transferring from an international to a US domestic flight you do have to collect and recheck bags, but not domestic - domestic or domestic - international